# Installing .NET 4.0 assemblies to GAC in XP and Windows 7 PCs

Tags: assemblies, gac

I needs to install .NET 4.0 assembly to GAC duing the MSI installation, target OS can be either XP and Windows7. I see there is a different is registering dlls to GAC in XP and windows7.

Could someone explain what should i consider during GAC installation ?

kuru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally GAC folder paths are different for `64` and `32` bit Dlls in `Win7`. Whereas in `XP` it resides under same folder. But when adding assembly to GAC through MSI we dont really need to worry about built version. based on the built version MSI will register them under 64 or 32 bit folders.